# Where is the icon used in this dialogue box?

Tags: macos, icon

Where on my disk can I find the icon used in this dialogue box in OS X？

[image]

It may be **Security.icns** in OS X 10.7.3

[image]

**I cannot find it in:**

1. `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes/Contents/Resources`
   There are only **LockedIcon.icns** and **UnlockedIcon.icns** in this folder who looks like the icon in the dialogue box,the size of the icon in the dialogue box is **128x128px**, but **LockedIcon.icns** and **UnlockedIcon.icns** is **32x32px**.

lockedIcon.icns

[image: **UnlockedIcon.icns** is **32x32px**]

**So they are not the same icon.**

2. `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/`
3. `/System/Library/CoreServices/Problem Reporter.app/Contents/Resources`
4. `/Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/Resources`
5. `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app/Contents/Resources`
6. `/System/Library/CoreServices/Certificate Assistant.app/Contents/Resources/`

Comment: The question is not clear? Do you mean the position in pixels?

Comment: Well,I'm a Chinese, ...I cannot express it in a right way

Comment: Now what the question asked is what I want to say

Answer (score 4):

### Lock Icon

The lock icon is located in

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
```

1. Install [Theme Engine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)

   **Note:** You may want to download the [released version](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases).
2. Open the file
3. Select `Security`
4. Drag the icon to the desktop to convert to a png

### [image]

### Finder Icon

macOS just places the app icon in front of it.

Comment: 是的，其中还包括了偏好设置重的时钟背景

Comment: The comment above translated:  Yes, it also includes a clock background with a preference setting. (Source: Google Translate)

Comment: @NickJonathan 请尝试使用英语发表评论。 谢谢！:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know where the system icons are stored.

Navigate to:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources
```

To do that easily, press cmd+shift+G, then enter the directory above and press **Go**.

You'll find all the system icons in this folder. Look for the one you want.

Comment: If ……it was there，I would not ask this question……

Comment: There are only LockedIcon.png and unLockedIcon.png in this folder who looks like the icon in the dialogue box

Comment: @NickJonathan The image in the dialog is probably composed of the finder icon (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/Finder.icns`) and the lock icon you mentioned

Comment: I have I have replaced the icon of Finder.Where is the Lock icon?

Comment: @NickJonathan The lock icon is LockedIcon.icns .  Arc676 suggests the icon you're looking for is composed using both LockedIcon.icns and FinderIcon.icn . I suggest you create it yourself using photoshop or something.

Comment: @onlyforthis,no,I know that the icon is composed using some icon and Findericon.icns, but the Lock icon is not LockedIcon,icns in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes/Contents/Resources

Comment: @onlyforthis，@Arc676, I want **to find the lock icon instead of the composed icon**, and, the lock icon is at last **128x128px**, while the LockedIcon.incs is **32x32px** in OS X 10.10+