# Where is the Keychain lock icon located?

Tags: macos, keychain, icon

By using Google and Co. and the built-in terminal command `locate`, I already found the following icons:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/UnlockedIcon.icns`
`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/LockedIcon.icns`

But their resolution is not very high.

I am looking for the icon that is displayed every time one has to authenticate (f.ex. when unlocking the keychain):

[image]

I think it exists without the little keys. I cannot find it under `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/`.

Do you know where this icon is hidden? Thanks a lot!

Related to this post: [Where is the icon used in this dialogue box?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223009/where-is-the-icon-used-in-this-dialogue-box)

Comment: Just for others; here's another tool that still seems to be maintained: https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer

Comment: T Meyer. Are you ok with closing as dupe?

Comment: Its basically the same, yes. Just found that question a bit later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn’t store all icons anymore for compound items and overlays the key icon over the lock icon in this case. The same with the [finder icon over the lock.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223009/where-is-the-icon-used-in-this-dialogue-box)

Here are the two sources:

### Lock Icon

The lock icon is located in

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
```

1. Install [Theme Engine](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)

   **Note:** You may want to download the [released version](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases).
2. Open the file
3. Select `Security`
4. Drag the icon to the desktop to convert to a png

### [image]

### Keychain Icon

macOS just places the app icon in front of it.  In this case the KeyChain icon is in

```
/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app/Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Finally got the answer. If you'd like to get some bonus (50 rep); I started a bounty on the old thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223009/where-is-the-icon-used-in-this-dialogue-box @JBis Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, any idea how to create a combined icon manually with Applescript or so?

Comment: @T.Meyer Photoshop? Preview? Don't think its possible in AppleScript. If you need a single image then I can make one for you in photoshop.

Comment: Ok. No, thats very kind, I already did it myself with the default Preview app (just a simple copy & paste and adjusting the image size). I was just wondering how Apple creates all the images for their dialogs (popups).

Comment: @T.Meyer Cocca probably. If you ask on SO you can prob find way to create that icon. May I ask why you need the icon?

Comment: Sure. I'd like to create a popup (or dialog) similar to Apple's that asks for a password. Therefore, I need an icon. To make things easier (for the user), I'd like to use the same icon as Apple does. @JBis

Comment: @T.Meyer Um. Why? Starting to sound like phishing....Anything that needs access will request access with system dialog

Comment: @T.Meyer For example in AppleScript you can use `do shell script "test" with administrator privileges`

Comment: It‘s for my own application, written in AppleScript. The user needs to authenticate with a password in order to continue. That‘s what the security box is for. @JBis

Comment: @T.Meyer  Ah. Gimme a hour. I'll show you how.

Comment: Oh, you don’t have to do this.

Comment: @T.Meyer  ok but check my example above.